# How to resolve DuplicateServiceException - Service jboss.cluster.web is already registered

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy ear file which contain three modules war file. When I trying to deploy into in standalone mode it deploy successfully. But when I try to deploy in ha environment (cluster mode). while deploying occur following exception.

> web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2
>   19:18:41,866 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."eis.ear"."1mec_mag.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."eis.ear"."1mec_mag.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "1mec_mag.war" of deployment "eis.ear"
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
>       **at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
>   Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018027: Failed to add JBoss Web deployment service**
>       at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:320)
>       at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:114)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: **org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.cluster.web is already registered**
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:154) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:227) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:560) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2228) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2228) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:307) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan.DistributedCacheManagerFactory.addDependencies(DistributedCacheManagerFactory.java:117)
>       at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:295)
>       ... 7 more

19:18:42,558 WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2